# Format Javascript,CSS,HTML with js-beautify

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, js-beautify

Currently i am using [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to format Javascript,CSS,HTML in my Java web based application but it down not support Java generics code

```
eg Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
```

What i have to modify in js-beautify so that it wont throw error when formatting HTML code which contain Java code as well.

Comment: Could you give a somewhat longer example of what the file looks like?